# SoftLayer REST API to order 100Mbps hardware firewall

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I can't find the REST API to order a 100Mbps hardware firewall for a virtual guest.

Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RestFul request this is something like this:

```
POST https://$USER:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder

payload:

{
    "parameters": [{
        "packageId": 557,
        "prices": [{
            "id": 409
        }],
        "quantity": 0,
        "virtualGuests": [{
            "id": 27488323
        }]
    }]
}
```

Note: replace the values as virtualGuests id and prices id

Basically you need to use the placeOrder method you can see here a documentation which exaplin how to use that method http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/going-further-softlayer-api-python-client-part-3